# jQuery Validate - Only two fields of four allowed to be filled - how to validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have four input fields:

```
MaxWidth
MaxHeight
```

and

```
Width
Height
```

I want to validate that only `MaxWidth + MaxHeight` or `Width + Height` has been entered. The user shouldn't be able to submit values for both sets.

Any idea?

---

**Update**

i'm using the jquery.validate.min.js supplied with .NET MVC3 default application

This is what i basicly need validation of

```
    <-- Scale a picture to one of the max attributes and keeping the aspect ratio --/>
    <input type="text" name="cmdMaxWidth" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="cmdMaxHeight" /><br />
    <br />
    <-- Scale a picture to the exact width and height attributes, still keeping the aspect ratio but addting whitespace for the rest --/>
    <input type="text" name="cmdWidth" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="cmdHeight" /><br />
```

---

**Update**

I've rewritten my form to reflect the UI/UX setup descriped by Mohen in the commands on his answer.

BUT i'll reward Jayendra Patil with the "accepted" answer, but i'll "flag up" Mohens answers and suggestions

Kind Regards
\T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also try to use validation with dependency.
Add a method which will check for the other two fields.
And make the required dependent on the other field.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/b3RmV/

Example for cmdMaxWidth field (ids hardcoded, you can pass as params)-

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("allowed", function(value, element) {
    return !($('#cmdWidth').val().length > 0 || $('#cmdHeight').val().length > 0)

}, "Not allowed");

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#commentForm").validate(
        {   rules: {     
                cmdMaxWidth: {       
                    required:  function(element){
                      return $('#cmdMaxHeight').val().length > 0;
                    },
                    allowed: true
                }   
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily disable other input when one is get a value.

For example you have this two inputs:

```
 <input id="width" placeholder="width"/>
  <input id="maxwidth" placeholder="max width"/>
```

and you want to not allow maxwidth entered when user entered width. Then you can do this:

```
$('#width').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() != ''){
    $('#maxwidth').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

You can do same vise versa for width and maxwidth

[JsBin File](http://jsbin.com/isamuv)

Comment: This seems fair on field to field "On/off", but it will get rather messy check when i have to check the fields in sets. If MaxWidth is set, then Width AND height shouldn't be entered and thats the same for alle the fields, it will always be 1 field entered 2 field to disable. And then the same the other way around, if a field is emptied, witch should the get activated and what if there still is entered something in the one pair... Think the code would get very messed up... Hope for a better solution, othervise i'll make a large validation based on you input

Comment: I just answered you question as you asked. I didn't even wrote whole code you need, that is your task to write code for other inputs. But if you are asking what is the best UI/UX to give user just two inputs at the same time then my answer would be completely different. I think you need a checkbox to ask your user if she/he wants enter maxheight/maxwidth or height/with rather than having four text inputs. Something like this http://jsbin.com/isamuv/2

Comment: Firstly, i stated in my question that i only wanted the user to be able to fill in one of the sets... I know, and certenly don't espect, people to write the code for me, but guide my in the correct direction... Lastly i like you aprouch with the checkbox to indicate if the giving value is a max or normal value... Thank you for that idea